# How to integrate loading screen on route change with redux in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

I am trying to add a loading screen whenever a URL change detect, So I am trying to put this code inside my _app.js file.

```
import Router from "next/router";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const start = () => {
      console.log("start");
      setLoading(true);
    };
    const end = () => {
      console.log("findished");
      setLoading(false);
    };
    Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", start);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", end);
    Router.events.on("routeChangeError", end);
    return () => {
      Router.events.off("routeChangeStart", start);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", end);
      Router.events.off("routeChangeError", end);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : (
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

But the issue is I am not able to attact redux.

My current code with Redux is this :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { wrapper } from "../redux/store"
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/media.css'



const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) =>(
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
);

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what the main issue is, and how Redux is relevant to it. Why not just add the `useState`/`useEffect` from the first block into your `MyApp` component? What actual issue are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Loading Component 
   const Loading = ()=>{
       return (
         <div> Loading gif here </div>
       )
   }

   const App = ()=>{
       const [currentPathname, setCurrentPathname] = useState<string>('');
       const router = useRouter();
       const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
       useEffect(() => {
          if (router.isReady) {
               if (router.pathname !== currentPathname) {
                   setLoading(true);
                   setCurrentPathname(router.pathname);
                   setTimeout(() => {
                      setLoading(false);
                   }, 3000);
          }
        }
      }, [router, router.pathname]);
    return (
        <Layout>
            {loading && <Loading />}
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

I assume that you have the loading component with some sort of loading gif.
I just check this solution inside my next app. Inside the useEffect, just check if the current path name is not the same then set the loading state to true to enable the loading component to show. Once it is enabled, set the current path name inside the local state and use a set timeout function to stop the loading after few seconds. In example, you will notice that I'm changing the loading state after 3 seconds

Comment: But, using this Redux will not work, See my code

Comment: No no, it is independent of redux. It just depends on the route doesn't matter redux is there or not. By the way, I test it in my own redux based app